# Error comparing Array elements in Google script

Tags: javascript, arrays, indexing

I have a problem in one of my scripts for a Google Spreadsheet.
In the script I create two arrays, the first one contains a column from the sheet:

```
    var sheet_data = sheet.getRange('C1:C').getValues(); // for example sheet_data = [[""],["text1"],["text2"],[""],["text3"]]
```

and the second one is hard-coded:

```
    var sheet_names = [["text1"],["text2"],["text3"]];
```

The sheet_data contains all elements present in sheet_names and I have a while function that finds one specific element (say text1) in sheet_data:

```
    i = 0;
    while (sheet_data[i] != sheet_names[1]) { i++; }
```

In short, I want to find the cell in the column C that contains a specific string. However the loop containing this condition doesn't work for some reason. The loop keeps going on and on but i never increases. I tried the same with a for loop containing an if statement but the if statement containing the above condition fails too. I assumed there must be something wrong with the condition but if I explicitly check the array elements that should be the same, it works:

```
    if (sheet_data[i] == "text1" && sheet_names[1] == "text1") // this works
```

Why doesn't the direct comparison of the two array elments work?

Comment: Thanks to @KevinQian for pointing out the array object differences. Since I'm dealing only with strings inside objects I managed to solve the problem by adding .toString() to both arrays inside the while loop. That makes sure that I'm converting objects to strings before comparing them.

Answer (score 1):

This looks more to me as a JavaScript issue (I am not familiar with Google Script flavor but the same logic should apply)

You are trying to `sheet_data[i] != sheet_names[1]`, where both `sheet_data[i]` and `sheet_names[1]` are `['text1']`. In JS, these are 2 different array objects (not same reference), so they would never equal to each other. (different from Python)

The reason that your second solution works is even tricker: when you do `['test1'] == 'test1'`, because the 2 elements are of different types, JavaScript will try to convert them to the same type, due to your use of `==` instead of `===`. `['test1']`'s stringified version is exactly `'test1'`, resulting in your second solution working.

See example below:

```js
console.log([] == []) // false, different object reference
console.log(['test'] == ['test']) // false
console.log('test' == 'test') // true, both are primitive
console.log(['test'].toString()) // 'test'
console.log(['test'] == 'test') // true, ['test'] converted to 'test' due to ==
console.log(['test'] === 'test') // false, strict comparison without type conversion

// More amazing JS tricks!
console.log([] == 0) // true
console.log([] == '') // true
console.log('' == 0) // true
console.log('' == false) // true
console.log(false == 0) // true
console.log([] == false) // true
// OOOPS...
console.log({} != true) // true
console.log({} != false) // true
// as you see here, NEVER USE == ! use === instead
```

Comment: Thanks to @Kevin for pointing out the array object differences. Since I'm dealing only with strings inside objects I managed to solve the problem by adding .toString() to both arrays inside the while loop. That makes sure that I'm converting objects to strings before comparing them.